# Ping-Pong Buffer OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to implement a DoF shader and I've been having trouble with the gaussian shader. 
I am trying to implement a ping pong buffer for my Gaussian blur shader but I am not able to understand why it does not work.

This is the loop for Ping-Pong

```
bool b = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, dof_FBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, b ? tmp_texture : blur_texture, 0);

    glViewport(0, 0, g_Width, g_Height);

    glUseProgram(gaussProgram);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(locUniformMVPM2, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp2[0][0]);
    glUniform1i(locColorTexture, b ? 3 : 4);
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(gaussProgram, "pixelSize"), 1.0 / g_Width, 1.0 / g_Height);
    glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(gaussProgram, "direccion"), 1, b ? &x[0] : &y[0]);

    drawQuad();
    b = !b;
}
```

tmp_texture is linked to GL_TEXTURE4 and blur_texture to GL_TEXTURE3

And that is how I initialized the FBO

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &dof_FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, dof_FBO);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, dpth_texture);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_texture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, dof_texture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, blur_texture, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
glDrawBuffers(3, DrawBuffers);
```

And this is the code of my shader.

```
#version330
uniform sampler2D uColorTexture;

in vec2 vTexCoord;

layout (location = 2) out vec4 fBlur;

uniform vec2 pixelSize;
uniform vec2 direccion;
uniform int kernel = 4;
const float values[9] = {0.05,0.09,0.11,0.15,0.2,0.15,0.11,0.09,0.05};
void main(){
    vec2 tc = vTexCoord;
    vec4 color = vec4(0);
    vec2 pos = -kernel * direccion * pixelSize;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1 + kernel * 2; i++){
        color += texture2D(uColorTexture, pos+tc) * values[i];
        pos += direccion * pixelSize;
    }

    fBlur = color;  
}
```

I've tried everything and no results hope someone can see what I can't.

**The main problem is that the result that appears on the screen implies that it only makes one iteration of the Ping-Pong loop.**

Thanks for reading.

**SOLUTION**:
*Since your FBO has a depth buffer attached, you either have to disable depth testing before drawing a quad or you clear the depth buffer.*

Comment: What does `glCheckFramebufferStatus` return? Have you set the correct draw buffers. Why do you use attachment 2? What is bound to attachment 0 and 1?

Comment: Everything works fine with the FBO and I'm using ATTACHMENT2 because it's where I keep the blur texture on the FBO.
In bound 0 and 1 are the color texture of the scene and a focus map.
The main problem is that the result that appears on the screen implies that it only makes one iteration of the Ping-Pong loop.

Comment: Did you call `glDrawBuffers` on that framebuffer?

Comment: I did it with these lines
GLenum DrawBuffers[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
glDrawBuffers(3, DrawBuffers);

Comment: (Not the answer, but please @ping users when replying to them not under their own posts, otherwise they might not a get a notification. I didn't.)

Comment: oh thanks @HolyBlackCat

Comment: It would be very important that you show us a complete example. Otherwise it's just random guessing. Did you disable depth testing? Since you don't clear after each iteration, this could prevent the quad from being drawn.

Comment: @BDL OMG it's solved it was the depth testing hahahah so much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your FBO has a depth buffer attached, you either have to disable depth testing before drawing a quad or you clear the depth buffer.